# How run test after fail in Cypress?

Tags: testing, cypress, e2e

Example:

1. I ran the tests in cypress.
2. Test accounts have been created
3. Next I get a failure in one of the tests
4. Test accounts remain created on the server
5. After failure, I want to delete the accounts I created. For it, I have the last `deleteCreatedUsers()` test, but I don't know how to run it after it fails. Since the tests are interrupted after the first failed test to save time.

I need a solution to run one test after something like `after` fails

I did try `after`, `afterEach` and default condition `if()`. After fail `after`, `afterEach` don't do anything.

Comment: Add the code that you tried.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is another place to put your code if you find `afterEach()` ***does not run*** when the test fails.

```js
Cypress.on('fail', (error, runner) => {
  deleteCreatedUsers();
})
```

The recommended approach from Cypress is to perform cleanup in `beforeEach()` as already mentioned, but the above event listener may also work depending on what you are doing inside `deleteCreatedUsers()`.

Comment: tried, not working, not run `deleteCreatedUsers()`((

Answer (score 2):

Also try the [After Run API](https://docs.cypress.io/api/plugins/after-run-api). It runs in the Node process of Cypress, set up in `cypress.config.js`.

It should always run after test run, pass of fail. But your `deleteCreatedUsers()` sounds maybe like browser-code, you will need to adapt it for the Node process.

```js
const { defineConfig } = require('cypress')

module.exports = defineConfig({
  // setupNodeEvents can be defined in either
  // the e2e or component configuration
  e2e: {
    setupNodeEvents(on, config) {
      on('after:run', (results) => {
        deleteCreatedUsers()
      })
    }
  }
})
```

---

It is also possible to run in `beforeEach()` instead of `afterEach()`, that way the tests are always starting with a clear users situation.

```js
beforeEach(() => {
  deleteCreatedUsers()
})
```

Comment: I need to `deleteCreatedUsers()` only after the failed test.

` on('after:run'` - I can't import in config my test

Comment: It's already imported - see `config` parameter in `setupNodeEvents(on, config)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an `afterEach` block that contains the [code here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73798137/11625850), and use the status of the test to determine whether or not to execute your code.

```js
afterEach(() => {
  if (Cypress.mocha.getRunner().suite.ctx.currentTest.state === 'failed') {
    deleteCreatedUsers();
  }
});
```

Comment: yes, but `deleteCreatedUsers()` isn't work(
`deleteCreatedUsers()` - it's the test case